# Call a function from another and returning results

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to call a function from another one (main function) but i can't see the returning values. When I try to run the function alone without parameters all goes well.

```
function main(){

  let sheetID = "***IDHERE***";
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);
  let sheetName = sheet.getSheetByName("SAMPLESHEET");
  let sheetData = sheetName.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().filter(data => data[0] != "");

  Logger.log(buscarRegistros(sheetData, 19));

}

function buscarRegistros(sheet, data){
  let sheetData = sheet;
  let input = data;
  let registros = [];

  for(i=0; i< sheetData.length; i++){
      if( sheetData[0] === input || sheetData[2] === input ){
        registros.push(i);
    }
  }
  return registros;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `sheetData` is a 2-dimensional array. And, all retrieved values are the string type. But, in your `buscarRegistros`, you are comparing an array and number at `if( sheetData[0] === input || sheetData[2] === input ){`. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
if( sheetData[0] === input || sheetData[2] === input ){
```

#### To:

```
if (sheetData[i][0] == input || sheetData[i][2] == input) {
```

#### Note:

- In your script, I thought that the following modification might be able to be also used.

  ```
    let sheetID = "***IDHERE***";
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);
    let sheetName = sheet.getSheetByName("SAMPLESHEET");
    let search = 19;
    let result = sheetName.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().filter(data => data[0] != "").flatMap((r, i) => (r[0] == search || r[2] == search) ? [i] : []);
  ```

#### References:

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)
- [Strict equality (===)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function main(){
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetID");
  let sh = ss.getSheetByName("SAMPLESHEET");
  let vs = sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().filter(data => data[0] != "");
  Logger.log(buscarRegistros(vs, 19));
}
function buscarRegistros(v,n){
  let a =v.map(r => {if(r[0] == n || r[2] == n) { return i;};})
  return a;
}
```